# How to run a rake task by command line in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have defined a rake task as follows in a file called `file_locker_task.rake`

```
namespace :myspace do
   task :process => :environment do
      FileLocker.lock_files   
   end
end
```

How do I execute this rake task from the command line?
I tried:

`rake myspace:process` and `rake process` but both are throwing an error like this:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'process'
```

Comment: where did you put that file?

Comment: also it should have the extension `.rake`

Comment: sorry the extension is rake

Comment: Rails pick up tasks in `lib/tasks`, is the file located  in that folder?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Run `rake -T -A` from your Rails home directory to see all the tasks that rake knows about. Yours must be in that list for rake to run it.
2. By default, in a Rails app, rake looks in the `lib/tasks` directory and its subdirectories for your `.rake` files. Check that. (I suspect this is the problem.)

Comment: it show s the task as rake file_locker_task:process how may I run this ?

Comment: Yes. you would run it exactly how it spells it out, with bundle exec in front: `bundle exec rake file_locker_task:process`, in this case.

Comment: Rails does not care where you put your `.rake` files. Did you mean Rake only looks `lib/tasks`? Btw see my answer below )

Comment: @hawk, I disagree. Rails configures rake to search `lib/tasks`. All custom Rails app rake tasks *should* be placed there, because this is where other developers will expect to find them. See pretty much [any tutorial](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial) on [rake + rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks).

Comment: @Dogweather Rails do nothing to run the tasks, only `rake` can run Rakefile, your 2nd answer is incorrect. Rails only looks in `lib/tasks` Rails is a framework not a task runner.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/doc/rakefile.rdoc)

> Any ruby file (including other rakefiles) can be included with a standard Ruby `require` command.

-

> Additional rake files (with the file extension “.rake”) may be placed in rakelib directory located at the top level of a project (i.e. the same directory that contains the main Rakefile). Also, rails projects may include additional rake files in the lib/tasks directory.